# left join and foreach displays no of rows of secondary table in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach

This is my function in the controller:

```
$bssr = table::('adv')
              ->leftjoin('picture', 'adv.id', '=', 'picture.advid')
              ->select('adv.*', 'picture.path)
              ->where('adv.id', '=', '1')
              ->paginate(20);


        return view('bssr.category')->with('bssr', $bssr);
```

Then I have my blade as follows:

```
@foreach($bssr as $data)
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%">
            <img src="{{url('avatar/'.$data->path) }}"> 
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="{{ url('details/'.$data->id) }}">{{ $data->advtopic }}</a>         
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
@endforeach
```

I have my tables as follows:

Table: adv

```
id      advtopic 
1       my adv name
```

Table :picture

```
id     path     advid
1      mypath1    1
2      mypath2    1
3      mypath3    1
```

Shouldn't my result in blade return only 1 row? 
The result gives 3 rows.

Can anyone help me to return only 1 row based on table 'adv'? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: $bssr = DB::table('adv')
              ->leftjoin('picture', 'adv.id', '=', 'picture.advid')
              ->select('adv.*', 'picture.path')
              ->where('adv.id', '=', '1')
              ->paginate(20);

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this:

```
$bssr = table::('adv')
              ->leftjoin('picture', 'picture.advid', '=', 'adv.id')
              ->select('adv.id AS Id','adv.advtopic AS advtopic', 'picture.path AS path')
              ->where('adv.id', '=', '1')
              ->groupBy('picture.advid')
              ->paginate(20);


        return view('bssr.category',compact('bssr'));

@foreach($bssr as $data)
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%">
            <img src="{{url('avatar/'.$data->path) }}"> 
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="{{ url('details/'.$data->Id) }}">{{ $data->advtopic }}</a>         
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
@endforeach
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply Addweb, however your solution returned the same result for me. 3 rows for 1 record from adv table. What I want is 1 row for every record from adv table by attaching one picture(path) from picture table.

Comment: @Tashi I think you should use groupBy

Comment: @Tashi Please check my updated answer i hope this help you

Comment: Thank you for your effort. For groupBy to work i had to do this: In config/database.php at "mysql" change :
'strict' => true,
to false... I hope changing this to false don't have any impact on my application.

Comment: @Tashi Thanks and follow this link(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) for upvote to answer in laravel

Comment: If not then please do it...@Tashi

Answer (score 0):

On your case, Yes, it will return 3 result because your query matches 3 rows on the left table (picture table). I don't know what you want to get from picture table, Do you want the recent one? the first one? or the last one? or just a random one?

```
$bssr = table::('adv')
          ->leftjoin('picture', 'adv.id', '=', 'picture.advid')
          ->select('adv.*', 'picture.path)
          ->where('adv.id', '=', '1')
          ->groupBy('adv.id') // try adding this if you want that result
          ->paginate(20);


return view('bssr.category')->with('bssr', $bssr);
```

Please modify your question so i can modify my answer to. Don't forget to include what you want to get on picture table.

Comment: Thank you Romnick for your reply. I did try adding groupBy before i posted my problem here. It returned the error: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bssr.adv.advtopic' isn't in GROUP BY. I am trying to achieve a result where only one row for one adv record is returned having adv.id, adv.advtopic, picture.path where the relation is on adv.id = picture.advid. Just one random result from picture will suffice so that i can display a picture for the record. As adv table will have several other records and it is a for loop, i would want to display all adv records just with one picture.

Comment: it should returned the thing that you want. What column did you group? `advtopic` is not in the query so why mysql return that error?

Comment: advtopic is another field in adv table which is retrieved from select('adv.*',... When groupBy is placed in the query the error seems to be thrown from the pagination. When i comment pagination the error disappears but without any result in the output. For groupBy to work I had to do this: In config/database.php at "mysql" change :
'strict' => true,
to false... Will that have any impact on my code in general?

Comment: i thought this issue is already been solved because you've already accepted this answer. However, what is the current status of your problem? are the errors same?

Comment: It is solved. For groupBy to work I had to do this: In config/database.php at "mysql" change : 'strict' => true, to false.